# Alinear FlowLayout a la izquierda

Tags: java, layout

> Sólo deseo que al añadir un componente a un Panel se alinee a la izda, pero no lo logro

```
    lbpanel=new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));


    lb=new JLabel("Impresora: Mi impresora");
    lbpanel.add(lb);
```

Comment: Cuando lo añades al JPanel, ¿dónde se te coloca? ¿Lo añades mediante código o mediante Java Swing arrastrando el elemento al JPanel? Si es posible añade una ilustración para que veamos el problema. Gracias.

Comment: Lo añado mediante código. Se aloja en el centro del panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lbpanel = new JPanel();
FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
lbpanel.setLayout(layout);
JLabel lb =new JLabel("Impresora: Mi impresora");
JLabel lb2 =new JLabel("Impresora: Mi impresora 2");
lbpanel.add(lb);
lbpanel.add(lb2);
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.